# Spring Security - проверка пользователя на авторизованность

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Для данных целей я использую шаблонизатор thymeleaf. Появилась необходимость для залогиненных юзеров добавлять панель профиля на главной странице, а для разлогиненных - скрывать, потому что она им просто не нужна. Как проверить "авторизован ли пользователь" из html?

Нашел вариант атрибута sec:autorize="isAuthenticated()", но он красный и не работает, даже после того, как добавил зависимость, точно не помню, как называется, но ее постоянно в ветке данных вопросов форсят.

Также использовал стандартный тимлифовский th:if, чего я только туда не ставил, но у меня ничего не вышло(

Каким образом можно реализовать данную задачу?

Заранее спасибо (:

Не помогло:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904176/thymeleaf-with-spring-security-how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in-or-not

https://blog.netgloo.com/2015/03/01/thymeleaf-check-if-the-user-is-authenticated-with-spring-security/

А это то, что я пытаюсь сделать:

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Site</a>
        <form class="d-flex" th:method="post" th:action="@{/logout}">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Выйти</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, возможно не совсем верный, но в качестве бонуса можно будет показать пользовательский логин.

```
<div th:if="${login != null}">
   <a href="/" th:text='${login}'></a>
</div>

<div th:if="${login == null}">
   <a href="/login">Войти</a>
</div>
```

А в контроллере запрашивать логин текущего пользователя у системы аутентификации Spring и добавлять его к модели.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/")
public String index(
        Model model
) {
    String login = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

    model.addAttribute("login", login);
    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать во `view` проверку `user` на `null`

Так-же в `Controller` в `GetMapping` добавить в сигнатуру `Principal principal`, а в методе добавить одну строчку :

```
model.addAttribute("user", Сервис.getUserByPrincipal(principal));
```